# error in fetching first element from collection

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to fetch first element from the collection like this

```
List<Entity> data = session.Query<Entity>()
                       .Fetch(x => x.Photos.First())
                       .ToList();
```

and I'm getting this error.
**A fetch request must be a simple member access expression; '[100002]' is a SubQueryExpression instead. Parameter name: relatedObjectSelector.**

Now I'm using .Fetch(x => x.Photos.First()) cause I know that first element will always be populated, and it is. I do need just first element from the collection to reduce loading time, so this is exact solution I need, but I'm getting this error.

Comment: just out of interest - would `x.Photos[0]` work? It eliminates the subquery

Comment: @Joanna same error message using x.Photos[0] as can be expected.

Comment: How about `session.Query<Entity>().Select(x => x.Photos).FirstOrDefualt().ToList();`...

Comment: @Willem thanks for posting, but not even close :) I do not need FirstOrDefault, First is just fine cause I know it always be populated. Also, I need fetch, that means that my entity will carry arround fetched object, in this case should only first element from collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch will fetch the entire collection, you can't tell it to just fetch the first element using "fetch", however you can probably get the desired effect using projections, or something like:

```
        var subQ = QueryOver.Of<Entity>()
            .SelectList(x => x.SelectMin(y => y.Photos)); // sub query selecting min photo id from entity

        List<Photo> data = session.QueryOver<Photo>()                
                               .Fetch(x => x.Entity).Eager // eager load the entity
                               .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(subQ) // restrict the photo to those that are the first ones for the entity
                               .List() // execute query from database
                               .ToList(); // convert to List
```

Although I'm not sure why you'd want a List instead of IList.. generally it's preferable to use the interface

Comment: this may work, but I have error inside vs intelisense in     .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(subQ) line.

Comment: This query now compiles when it's change List<Photo> to IList<Photo>.... How can I cast this to List?

Comment: edited to return a List<Photo> instead of IList<Photo> (just call .ToList() )

Comment: if you have enough time I would like to comment this query over query. Just to have basic understanding.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Entity> data = session.Query<Entity>()
      .Fetch(x=>x.Photos.FirstOrDefualt())//here You need get only first element          
      .ToList();
```

Comment: the OP mentioned that the first element is always populated, so the FirstOrDefault won't solve it. Anyway, if that was the issue it would throw a NullRef exception

Comment: @abaha please double check your though before posting.